# Function doesn't count emojis

Tags: python, function, emoji

I'm getting a s=0 result when executing this code:

```
import emojis
import emoji
from collections import Counter

#count emoji
#function to check if sth is an emoji
def char_is_emoji(character):
    return character in emoji.UNICODE_EMOJI

#function to count emoji
def emoji_counter(text_string):
    count = 0
    for x in text_string:
        a = char_is_emoji(x)
        if a ==True:
            count+=1
    return count

#test
s = " Last clue! \nWho's the host of"
print(emoji_counter(s))
```

Any ideas why? Any help much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

In my version of `emoji` (v1.6.1), `emoji.UNICODE_EMOJI_ENGLISH` works:

```py
import emoji

def emoji_counter(s):
    return sum(c in emoji.UNICODE_EMOJI_ENGLISH for c in s)

s = " Last clue! \nWho's the host of"
print(emoji_counter(s)) # 2
```

Or try `emoji.UNICODE_EMOJI['en']` (https://github.com/carpedm20/emoji/issues/155):

> From the v.1.0.0 added support for multilingual naming of emojis. Now `UNICODE_EMOJI` has language keys
>
> ```
> UNICODE_EMOJI = {
> 'en': UNICODE_EMOJI_ENGLISH,
> 'es': UNICODE_EMOJI_SPANISH,
> 'pt': UNICODE_EMOJI_PORTUGUESE,
> 'it': UNICODE_EMOJI_ITALIAN,
> }
> ```

Comment: Thanks! Specifying the language with ```emoji.UNICODE_EMOJI_ENGLISH``` worked!